# How to create links between dynamic content using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

What is the best way to create links between dynamically-generated HTML content with JavaScript?

For example, I have a number of thumbnail images on a homepage that should open the matching project when clicked. I've come up with this solution but I'm sure there's a better way that doesn't involve using split() to select the correct class?

The order of the thumbnails and projects will be randomised so I can't use the index of the thumbnail to open the project page with the same index.

https://codepen.io/wrgt1/pen/OJRwNQv

```js
const thumbnail = document.querySelectorAll(".thumbnail");
const project = document.querySelectorAll(".project");

thumbnail.forEach(function (thumb) {
    thumb.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
        
        const splitClass = e.target.className.split(" ")[1];
        const target = `.${splitClass}:not(.thumbnail)`;
        const targetSelector = document.querySelector(target);

        for (let i = 0; i < project.length; i++) {
            project[i].style.visibility = "hidden";
        }
            
        targetSelector.style.visibility = "visible";
        
    });
});
```

```css
#thumbnails, #projects {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
}

.thumbnail, .project {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  margin: 10px;
}

.thumbnail {
  background: #FF7400;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.project {
  visibility: hidden;
  background: #209209;
}
```

```html
<div id="thumbnails">
  <div class="thumbnail project1">Thumbnail (Project 1)</div>
  <div class="thumbnail project2">Thumbnail (Project 2)</div>
  <div class="thumbnail project3">Thumbnail (Project 3)</div>
</div>
<div id="projects">
  <div class="project project1">Project 1</div>
  <div class="project project2">Project 2</div>
  <div class="project project3">Project 3</div>
</div>
```

I'd be really grateful for any ideas!

Comment: What do you mean by the "best" way? What's wrong with what you have done so far?

Comment: I'm not sure if using the split() method is the best to select the correct class (.project#) as it relies on the classes being in the correct order. Is there a way to select the 'other' class on the clicked element regardless of the order the classes are in?

Comment: Why not use `element.classList` instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't see anything wrong with your code, I have also tried it in some different way

Hope you take a look at the same also

```js
const thumbnail = document.querySelectorAll(".thumbnail");
const project = document.querySelectorAll(".project");

thumbnail.forEach(function (thumb) {
    thumb.addEventListener("click", (e) => {        
        const target = e.target.classList[1];
        project.forEach(function (pro) {
            pro.style.visibility = "hidden";
            if( pro.classList.contains(target)){
              pro.style.visibility = "visible";
            }
        });        
    });
});
```

```css
#thumbnails, #projects {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
}

.thumbnail, .project {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  margin: 10px;
}

.thumbnail {
  background: #FF7400;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.project {
  visibility: hidden;
  background: #209209;
}
```

```html
<div id="thumbnails">
  <div class="thumbnail project1">Thumbnail (Project 1)</div>
  <div class="thumbnail project2">Thumbnail (Project 2)</div>
  <div class="thumbnail project3">Thumbnail (Project 3)</div>
</div>
<div id="projects">
  <div class="project project1">Project 1</div>
  <div class="project project2">Project 2</div>
  <div class="project project3">Project 3</div>
</div>
```